# Doctrine query fails when returning more than 13578 records

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a symfony 2.8 app that uses a doctrine query to generate a paginated list to display all the records in the a table of applicants. Worked great until recently.

Now when I navigate to the page I get an error message in IE and Chrome or blank screen in Firefox.

The HTTP headers show a 500 error but there is nothing in my symfony log or in my PHP error log (error logging is switched on in php.ini)

I thought there was a code problem, so have spent a few hours trying to debug the issue.

After inserting numerous try/catch, echo, debug, print_r and var_dump statements as well as testing the runnable query against the database, going through the actual data, setting limits and querying partial sets I know for certain that the **issue only arises if I try to return more than 13578 records in my application**.

This is my querybuilder statement:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select("a")
    ->from("ApplicationBundle:Applicant", "a")
    ->where("a.id > 0 ");

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I can return the actual SQL, run it against the database and get everything, but I don't get anything returned by the `getResult()` call. Not even an error!

Works fine if I change it to:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select("a")
    ->from("ApplicationBundle:Applicant", "a")
    ->where("a.id < 13579 ");

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And to discount the possibility of the data in the table being corrupt, I tested the following and it also works:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select("a")
    ->from("ApplicationBundle:Applicant", "a")
    ->where("a.id > 13578 ");

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I have searched for documentation on any limits to the maximum size of the resultset but have not found anything.  Does anyone know if this is a limit set by doctrine/symfony or has anyone encountered a similar issue and managed to overcome it?

**EDIT**

1. I am using KNPPaginatorBundle to paginate the records
2. php.ini Max memory has already been doubled

Comment: check error logs im betting on out of memory

Comment: Have you looked at the KnpPaginatorBundle already? 13579 results is a lot to handle.

Comment: Why would you pull 13579 results at once? Look in to `yield`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: Forgot to mention I have already doubled the maximum memory a script may use to 256M.

Comment: I am already using KNP paginator to paginate the result set

Comment: Please see this link. You shouldn't have to return more records than you intend to show on a single page.. https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per nogad's suggestion it was memory related.

I had edited my php.ini file and increased the available maximum memory but when I checked in the IIS PHP manager settings the old value was still present.  I increased it to match the setting in php.ini and the site is working again.